# removing upgrade windows 8.1 banner

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-8.1-upgrade

If I change the registry with

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\UpgradeNotification' -Name UpgradeAvailable -Value 0 #
```

Will I still get regular updates?

Comment: Are you on 8.0 and trying to block the 8.1 offer, or on 8.1 and blocking the "8.1 Update 1" offer, or what?

Comment: You do understand that eventually Windows 8 will not be supported right?  Why are you purposefully not upgrading to 8.1?

Comment: @BenVoigt this disable the automatic upgrade from 8.0 to 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you still get regular updates for Windows 8. I do the same to avoid the automatic upgrade to 8.1 because I use a highly customized Windows 8 (Aero glass, Startmenu) which only causes issues during upgrade. I'll upgrade to Windows 10 when it is RTM and so I skip Windows 8.1.